# AutoFac ContainerBuilder.RegisterModule throwing EntryPointNotFoundException in Azure Functions

Tags: autofac, azure-functions

I'm trying to migrate a small WebAPI project to Azure Functions v1. We use AutoFac for IoC.

When trying to register a module configured in a Json file, the function thows an EntryPointNotFoundException. AFAIK it scans the Assembly to register the module, so there may be something different in Azure Functions assembly that causes this issue.

I tried running the same test code in Console App, WebApi app and the code works with no issue.

Is it feature of AutoFac supported in Azure Functions? If not is there a workaround? Thanks.

```
ContainerBuilder builder = new ContainerBuilder();
ConfigurationBuilder configurationBuilder = new ConfigurationBuilder();
configurationBuilder.AddJsonFile("config.json");
var module = new ConfigurationModule(configurationBuilder.Build());
builder.RegisterModule(module);
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not too sure how you implemented your solution. You may need to add the assembly in question as a custom assembly to make it available to autofac. Have a look here [Azure Functions C# script (.csx) developer reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-reference-csharp). There is a paragraph called "Referencing external assemblies". It probably solves your issue.

When you want to go with a different approach I did write a blog entry for dependency injection in Azure functions with autofac.

[Azure Function Dependency Injection with AutoFac: Autofac on Functions](http://codingsoul.de/2018/01/19/azure-function-dependency-injection-with-autofac/)

There are some more approaches out there, at the end of the post, I listed some of them.